# Javascript new Image() not loading image

Tags: javascript, image

I am creating a new image via javascript loading the url but when it comes to loading it on the screen it doesn't and through further investigation i found that after i load the image the image is not setting the height and width. This is the code i am using to create and draw the image.

```
var img = createImage("./Images/saveButton.png");
context.drawImage(img, 50, 50);
var oldback = context.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64);
context.drawImage(img, 50, 50);
var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64);
```

Why is this happening as i believe i have done everything correctly?

Comment: I do not fully understand your code/question but you have to wait for the image to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `createImage` does, but I suppose it just creates a new instance, like this:

```
var createImage = function (url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    return img;
}
```

The problem is that the image can only be draw to a canvas element if it is already loaded, so you must provide an `onload`callback:

```
var createImage = function (url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    callback();
    img.src = url;
    return img;
};

createImage("./Images/saveButton.png", function () {
    context.drawImage(img, 50, 50);
    var oldback = context.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64);
    context.drawImage(img, 50, 50);
    var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 64, 64);
});
```

Comment: "Try this" does not constitute a good answer. Please explain what your answer does and why it will work. Code dump answers are no good!

Comment: Additionally, take a look at the [MDN canvas tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial), especially the [Using Images page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images).